# In protractor, How to grab a number of values in the exact time for application with massive push notification

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm creating automation test using protractor for an application that gets massive push notification, the problem is that I tries to test a simple logic

```
expect(A + B).toEqual(C);
```

The problem is that A, B and C taking from different time and the test fail, there is a way to pause the browser for gitting push notification, execute the test and after the test done, continue.

Or is there is other way I be more then happy to know.

```
element.all(by.css('#footer > span')).getTest().then(function(information){
       expect(information[0] + information[1]).toEqual(information[2]);
});
```

Comment: How does the test fail? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @alecxe, its fail because the 3 values A,B and C taking from different period of time, protractor slower than the push notification, for Example protractor need to calculate if A + B = C, protractor taking A, B and C changing (push notification), so A + B != C , the test fail.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming there are less than 3 notifications at the moment the expectation is made. If this is the case, you may add an explicit wait to wait for N elements to become present:

```
function waitForNElementsToBePresent(n) {
    return function () {
        return element.all(by.css('#footer > span')).count().then(function (count) {
            return count >= n;
        });
    }
}

browser.wait(waitForNElementsToBePresent(3), 5000);

element.all(by.css('#footer > span')).getText().then(function(information){
   expect(information[0] + information[1]).toEqual(information[2]);
});
```